# sed with multiple commands, can I use the w (write) flag?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Here I am learning sed, here it is with multiple commands:

```
(user@host)-(18:27:39)-(~/Bash_Programming)
$sed '4 { s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/ }' catAndDog.txt 
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy cat
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**But where do I put the w substitution flag if I'm using multiple commands and want the results wrote to a file?**

```
w file = write the result of the substitution to a file
```

EDIT:

**I want to write the whole output to the file, a copy of the original with the changes made.**

Comment: It seems your command is doing wat you want it to do. You just have to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: @Kusalananda yea but maybe I'm not clear enough, I wanted to know how I would use or if it was possible to use the `w` flag to output the changes to a file

Comment: @don_crissti I already learned a lot from this question and his answer, yes I have a reason, I am learning `bash` and `sed` and `awk` and I was curouius if the `w flag` is used when there are more than one command and if then how because I couldn't get it to work, but now I know about the `w command`, but I still haven't gotten the answer if I can use the `flag`

Comment: Well, if you have more than one `s` command and use `w` flag with each one then it's obvious it will apply to each successful substitution so it will write the modified line each time e.g. with your example you get two lines written, 1st one is `The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy dog` and the 2nd one is `The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy cat`. So technically speaking the answer is NO,  you can't do it if you use the `w` flag with each `s` command... you need either some branching _or_ cheating ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are **two** `w` elements. One is a command, the other is a `s///` flag.

Both are used to **write** the present pattern space to a file.

#### command

For example, this `w` command will write to `outfile` (make a copy):

```
$ printf '%s\n' AA BB CC DD EE > infile
$ sed -n 'w outfile' infile
$ cat outfile
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
```

The `-n` option avoid printing any pattern space, but the `w` command will `write` each pattern (line) to the filename in the argument after the `w` command (that should end the command).

This, instead, will write only one line (the line that has (at least) one `C`):

```
$ sed -n '/C/ w outfile' infile ;  cat outfile
CC
```

#### flag

The other `w` element is the `w` flag to the `s///` command, which altough it means about the same `write`, it only gets executed if the substitution in the `s///` command got executed:

```
$ sed -n 's/C/X/w outfile' infile; cat outfile
XC
```

## Q1

> **But where do I put the w substitution flag if I'm using multiple commands and want the results wrote to a file?**

As a substitution flag is connected to one (specific) substitution, where should it be used depends on which substitution needs to be recorded:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/B/X/w outfile' -e 's/D/Y/' infile; cat outfile
XB
```

Note that each substitution must be in separate `-e` (or separate lines) as the name of the output filename must end the command (needs a newline), or could be written as:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/B/X/w outfile
> s/D/Y/' infile; cat outfile
XB
```

The other substitution could be selected with:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/B/X/' -e 's/D/Y/w outfile' infile; cat outfile
YD
```

Or both:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/B/X/w outfile' -e 's/D/Y/w outfile' infile; cat outfile
XB
YD
```

Or use the `w` command (not flag) (and assuming GNU sed):

```
$ sed -n 's/B/X/;s/D/Y/;w outfile' infile; cat outfile
AA
XB
CC
YD
EE
```

## Q2

> **I want to write the whole output to the file, a copy of the original with the changes made.**

A **substitution** flag can not write the **whole** file unless the substitution happens for all the lines. You need to use the `w` command (assuming bash):

```
$ printf 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog%.0s\n' {1..14} >catAndDog.txt
$ sed -n '4 { s/fox/elephant/ ; s/dog/cat/ } ; w outfile' catAndDog.txt
$ cat outfile
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy cat
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Understand that a `w` flag for each substitution will print a line for each substitution, so this will happen:

```
$ sed -n -e '4 { s/fox/elephant/w outfile' -e 's/dog/cat/w outfile' -e '}' catAndDog.txt
$ cat outfile
The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy cat
```

Comment: _"A substitution flag can not write the whole file unless the substitution happens for all the lines."_ Exactly, which means that you _can_ do it using the `w` flag... if you're sneaky enough :P , as I mentioned in a comment above.

Answer (score 2):

In respons to:

> I want to write the whole output to the file, a copy of the original with the changes made.

You can either redirect to a file like

```
sed '4{ s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/}' infile > modified_file
```

Or modify in-place with `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '4{ s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/}' infile
```

... or take a backup from original file and write the changes with same original filename.

```
sed -i.backup '4{ s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/}' infile
```

Or with `w` command:

```
sed '4{ s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/ }; w modified_file' infile
```

---

If you only wants to write the lines that  `s` command substitution was successful (which is not what you are asking for currently), with using the `w` flag you can do:

```
sed '4{ s/fox/elephant/; s/dog/cat/w modified_file
}' infile
```

Comment: The 1st revision was better... Your last edits do more harm than good... It only works with OP sample, as soon as `dog` is no longer present in that line it no longer writes the modified line even if the previous substitution was successful...

Answer (score 2):

> But where do I put the w substitution flag if I'm using multiple commands and want the results wrote to a file?

The `w` flag must be terminated with a newline or must be the last item (including it argument) in a sed script. If whitespace, comments or semicolons are found, they will be included in the filename.

Do not confuse the `w` flag associated to the command substitution `s` (`s///w`) and the `w` command. They are similar but the `w` flag is only used if the substitution is performed. Note that the `w` command may be used conditionally or unconditionally depending on the sed script (use cases).

Note: the option `i` (`--in-place`) is not specified by POSIX.

**First example**

```
prompt% sed -i.back -e "/$regex/w output" -e "/$regex/d" input
```

**Second example**

```
prompt% sed -i.back "/$regex/ {
w output
d;}" input
```

**Someone may encounter an issue with your case** (see below) because several substitutions are performed on the same input line.

```
prompt% sed -n '4 { 
s/fox/wolf/w output
s/dog/bear/w output
}' input
```

There is only one input line modified but the output file contains two lines.

```
The quick brown wolf jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown wolf jumps over the lazy bear
```

This result is not convenient because it is misleading.

> I want to write the whole output to the file, a copy of the original with the changes made.

My solution allows to create a backup of the original file (`input.back`), apply changes in the original file (`input`) and write potential substitutions in another file (`output`). This algorithm uses the `w` command.

```
prompt% sed -i.back -nE '4!p       # print line except 4th
4!d                                # delete line except 4th
/fox|dog/!p                        # print line if no "fox" or no "dog"
/fox|dog/!d                        # don't delete line if "fox" or "dog"
s/fox/wolf/                        # substitution occurs if "fox"
s/dog/bear/                        # substitution occurs if "dog"
p                                  # if a substitution then print 4th line
w output' input                    # if a change then save 4th line in "output"
```

The command `/fox|dog/!d` immediately starts the next cycle if `fox` or `dog` is not found (none of them). Therefore, if a keyword is not found, the following commands (`s///`, `p`, `w`) are not processed for the current line.